# Error in unintuitive place reading in DataList

Tags: sql, datalist, sqldatareader, sqlconnection, itemtemplate

```
***ERROR***
***********
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
***********
Line: <td>< asp:Label ID="Label59" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("field2").Equals("") ? "" : Eval("field3") + " " + Eval("field4") + " " + Eval("field 5") %>' /></td>
***********
***********
```

Hi,

Appreciate being able to get any feedback.  I'm somewhat new to ASP.NET using 3.5

Getting error after adding a new field to an existing sqlreader class.  The error is supposedly pointing to a null value in a datalist.  But if this one line is removed there is no problem for the entire ItemTemplate.

> _var= reader["field"] != null ? (int)reader["field"] : 0;

The only other change to the `sqlreader` class is the new field's get set.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `field2` contains `null`, `Eval("field2")` will be `null` so you'll get a null-ref while calling `Equals` on it. Simply swap the operands:

```
<%# "".Equals(Eval("field2")) ? "" : Eval("field3") + " " + Eval("field4") + " " + Eval("field 5") %>
```

Although I'd recommend comparing with `null` which is more readable and likely more correct.

Comment: Thanks for the assist.  This got me past the error.  Was confusing because there were no null entries.  Reading Asp.Net.  Ended up doing things a little different without DataList for this page.